# Why isn't a template displaying model data?

Tags: ractivejs

We have a template that loops over keys in a data model subobject. If the subobject is an Array it works fine. If the subobject is a map it does not. No data is disiplayed. It is just like there are no keys present. Important to note is that the elements of the Array or the map keys are added dynamically. Observers added to the model work properly regardless of whether they are assigned to map keys or Array indexes with wild cards. And an inspection of the data shows that all expected elements are indeed present.

Is this expected behavior? There is a note in the Ractive docs saying that it can only respond to pre-existing keys.

If is is not expected behavior, is there a bug number I can track? I can't find one based on a GitHub search.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a small demo for this?

Comment: Here is a JS Fiddle demo of the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/pc94L28x/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ractive doesn't know that you want to iterate over the object's properties (as opposed to using the object as *context* for the contents of that section). You can help it out by being explicit with the `{{#each ...}}` keyword:

```html
{{#each entities[name]}}
  <li>{{title}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj3wmega/

You can also give the block a `:key` to let Ractive know you want to iterate (or in the `#each` case as well to get access to the key value):

```html
{{#entities[name]:key}}
    <li>id: {{key}} title: {{title}}</li>
{{/}}
```

Comment: Thanks Marty and Rich ... written 1,000s of lines of Ractive code. Would have thought I should have run into this before ... or at least been able to figure it out.